# How do I access the data list outside the class with Kivy and Python

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to create a grid and want to retrieve the data of users in a list I am parallelly working on mysql as well so as to add the data in it so I basically want to get access to the data list which I have used in the pressed method in the AppLayout Class so as to go ahead.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class Applayout(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self , **kwargs): 

        super(Applayout , self).__init__(**kwargs)
        

        self.cols = 1

        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 2

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "First Name: "))
        self.first_name = TextInput(multiline = False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.first_name)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "Last Name: "))
        self.last_name = TextInput(multiline = False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.last_name)

        self.inside.add_widget(Label(text = "Email: "))
        self.email = TextInput(multiline = False)
        self.inside.add_widget(self.email)

        self.add_widget(self.inside)

        self.submit = Button(text = "Submit", font_size = 40)
        self.submit.bind(on_press = self.pressed) 
        self.add_widget(self.submit)

    def pressed(self , instance):
        first_name = self.first_name.text
        last_name = self.last_name.text
        email = self.email.text

        person_data = {"First Name": first_name , "Last Name": last_name , "E-Mail": email}
        data = []
        data.append(person_data)

        print(f"Name: {first_name} {last_name} , E-Mail: {email} ")
        print("Submitted")

        self.first_name.text = ""
        self.last_name.text = ""
        self.email = ""


class Granth_BagadiaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Applayout()



if __name__  == "__main__":
    Granth_BagadiaApp().run()
```

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()
    def datas(self):
        return MyGrid().data
```

This is what I did
But now how do I print this
Cause on typing
`print(MyApp().datas())`
I get
`[{'Name': <ObjectProperty name=nameee>, 'E-Mail': <ObjectProperty name=emailll>}]`

Comment: first you have to use `self.` to have access outside class - ie. `self.data`

Comment: second: you should show how you try to run function with SQL - maybe you should simply use `function(self.data)` to send values as arguments to this function. Eventually you may need to assign data to external/global variable to have access from all places. OR you should assign class to global variable - `al = Applayout()` and use `return al` and then you can use `al.data` in other functions/classes to access `self.data`

Comment: and about the sql thing
i am able to do that but that makes my code very long so i want to write all that in another file and call the list from here

Comment: always put code, data and error message in question, not comment - it will be more readable and more people will see it.

Comment: I have changed it

Comment: don't use `MyGrid()` many times because ever `MyGrid()` create new instance and new instance has empty `data`. You should create `MyGrid()` at start - `my_grid = MyGrid()` and then you have only one instace which you should use in `return my_grid` and `return my_grid.data`

Answer (score 0):

All depends how you want to use it.

---

Normally I would run directly function with SQL and send `data` as argument.

```
class Applayout()

    def pressed(self, instance):
        data = [{
            "First Name": self.first_name.text, 
            "Last Name": self.last_name.text, 
            "E-Mail": self.email.text
        }]

        function_with_sql(data)
        #other_object.function_with_sql(data)

        # ... other code ...
```

Eventually I would use `queue` to communicate with other process.

```
class Applayout()

    def pressed(self, instance):
        data = [{
            "First Name": self.first_name.text, 
            "Last Name": self.last_name.text, 
            "E-Mail": self.email.text
        }]

        queue_to_other_process.put(data)

        # ... other code ...
```

---

But if I would have to give access to data then first I would use `self.data`

```
class Applayout()

    def __init___(...):
        self.data = [] # default value at start 

        # ... other code ...

    def pressed(self, instance):
        self.data = [{
            "First Name": self.first_name.text, 
            "Last Name": self.last_name.text, 
            "E-Mail": self.email.text
        }]

        # ... other code ...
```

and I would assign class to global variable

```
applayout = Applayout()

class Granth_BagadiaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return applayout
```

and now everyone can access data as `applayout.data`.

---

Eventaully I would create `data` as external object and send `data` to `Applayout` and other classes as argument.

```
data = []

class Applayout()

    def __init___(..., data):
        self.data = data   
        
        # ... other code ...
        
    def pressed(self, instance):
        self.data.clear()  # not `self.data = []` because it will remove access to external `data`
        
        self.data.append({
            "First Name": self.first_name.text, 
            "Last Name": self.last_name.text, 
            "E-Mail": self.email.text
        })

        # ... other code ...

applayout = Applayout(data)

class Granth_BagadiaApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return applayout
```

Of course with external `data` you could use `data` directly in classes -  without sending it as argument - but as says [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) `"Explicit is better than implicit."` - and it means `data` as argument.

Comment: I did this but it just prints the last input by user

Comment: But I guess I should directly connect with sql to make it easier

Comment: it would be better to run it directly `function_with_sql(data)` - and then you can be sure it runs in current data. If you run it in separated process then you can't be sure if `data` has all data - especially that you used `data = []` (and I used `data.clear()`) to remove previous data. Maybe you shouldn't remove data - `data = []` - but it should do process which runs SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your response I actually did that but have got stuck somewhere else
If possible could you please help me with that
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66074961/i-am-using-kivy-and-mysql-for-a-login-page-and-want-to-switch-window-by-the-vari